# Get indexes from list<>

Tags: c#, list

hi i have this following code in my project

```
class CVote
{
    public int id;
    public int studentId;
    public string answer;
    public int questionIndex;
    //public DateTime occurred;
}

public static List<CVote> votes = new List<CVote>();
```

I want to get indexes of certain studentID (ex : studentID 15)
so i try this following code

```
int test = -1;
test = Global.votes.IndexOf(15);
```

but it's end with error result

1. Invalid argument
2. Can't convert from int to CVote

any idea how to do it correctly?

Comment: [List<T>.FindIndeks()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `FindIndex`

```
var std = votes.FindIndex(x=>x.id == 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (to have `IndexOf`)

```
var element = Global.votes.SingleOrDefault(e=>e.id==15);
if(element!=null)
 {
  var index = Global.votes.IndexOf(element);
 }
```

or use `FindIndex` to have it directly

```
public static bool Find15(CVote vote){
  if(vote.id==15) return true;
  return false;
}
var index = Global.votes.FindIndex(e=>e.id==15);
```

Comment: What if there is no element that matches `e.id==15`

Comment: You will get element as null. So before calling var index = Global.votes.IndexOf(element); check if(element != null)

Comment: @PM.: won't it be an exception instead?

Comment: @PM Single will throw an exception if element is missing ( I assumed it must exists). If you want to handle null's use `SingleOrDefault`

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOf` takes an argument of the same type as the elements in the `List`(`CVote` in your example) and returns the index of that element if it finds it, and -1 if it doesn't